# Starting my own simple UI toolkit

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, user-interface

I hope this question isn't too subjective. I would like to start my own **simple** UI toolkit in C++, i.e. a library that can create UI across many platforms (more or less an ipersimplified version of QT's basics) by rendering all of its controls. I'm doing this for learning's sake so please refrain from posting *You should not reinvent the wheel* since competing with major UI toolkits is really not my goal.

The question is: which API should I use on Windows and Linux to create my toolkit?

I researched a bit around and I suppose I should draw everything with GDI+ on Windows and perhaps cairo on Linux (not sure about these two).

Drawing a UI with openGL is probably doable but

1. Would require way more work
2. Would probably not be the best thing to do since openGL is a series of primitives optimized for 3D graphics, not 2D ones

So the question really is: which API should I use on Windows and Linux to start this project?
I hope I narrowed it down enough to make it answerable objectively.

Comment: GDI+ will serve almost all of your 2D needs on Windows. Basic GDI calls will almost always suffice.

Comment: @cppguy The problem with GDI+ is that it only exists for Windows (and in Wine). If you draw using GDI+ on Windows, you will get different results than drawing using other drawing systems. Thus using native GDI+ in a cross-platform toolkit is a very bad idea, it leads to more problems than it solves. One can use GDI+ from Wine, or Cairo, or perhaps Blend when that becomes available...

Comment: MS-Windows UI and the X protocol, used on Linux, couldn't be more dissimilar. Whichever one you pick, your work with generally mean very little, on the other platform. Cross-platform toolkits, like QT, tend to be either somewhat awkward on platforms other than the ones they're based on; or, in order to achieve cross-platform interoperability, they restrict themselves to a small sliver of functionality on all platforms, and are unable to take advantage of each platform's unique features.

Comment: Learn QtQuick + Qt3D ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing with any platform-specific API will not work, since you want to draw on multiple platforms and their APIs don't overlap and don't work the same. There's a very good reason why toolkits like Qt or WPF don't use native drawing: it doesn't work. I mean, come on, even Microsoft's own WPF doesn't.

Most likely you'll want to do exactly what Qt does: have your own raster drawing back-end. You can use [cairo](http://cairographics.org) or some other library for the nitty-gritty of that. If you wanted rich computational geometry functionality (curve intersections, interior/exterior checks, etc.), you can leverage [cgal](http://www.cgal.org) as an implementation detail of that. It'd let you implement equivalents to `QPainterPath`, `QPolygon`, etc. quickly, and likely with better results than in Qt.

What you can also do much better compared to Qt is widget composition and multithreading. Right now, Qt's widgets are single-thread only, but they don't have to be. When widgets are drawn on the top-level backing store, they are composited, and this happens in Z order, serially. This doesn't have to be the case, though - overlapping widgets form a tree, and multiple nodes in that tree can be rendered and composited in parallel. That's one thing that Qt will never fix, since the widgets module is considered finished, more or less. You also don't need to include monstrosities like `QPixmap` that made sense in pre-Qt 4.2 days, but doesn't anymore.

Finally, you probably should stick with modern C++11 and its containers - you'll avoid a lot of cruft that way. Qt didn't have the freedom to do that, and won't for a while. You'll probably want to leverage boost as well.

On either platform, the APIs you will be using for user interaction are whatever is needed to update window contents with your own image bitmap, and event loop. Thus, WINAPI on Windows, XCB (in preference over Xlib) for X11 screens, VNC for itself, Cocoa for OS X. Qt reuses glib for its event loop on X11 systems, but I don't know enough about it to make a recommendation.

Comment: Why so much Qt hate? Yes, it's not perfect, but on other hand - there is nothing better around (even in non C/C++ world).
Personally, I hope for new Qt successor on Rust. Because there is no need in 'fixing' of C++ legacy, which is half of Qt code is does.

Comment: @RazrFalcon It's not Qt hate, it's reality. I'm a hardcore Qt proponent, but I understand its shortcomings, too. Qt's biggest benefit is a huge, well tested code base. It's also its drawback, since it's hard to change without introducing new code that's sure to have bugs. Everything I develop for desktop uses Qt :), and quite a bit of server code as well.

Comment: Thanks, a good overview of what I need. I'll probably stick with cairo (it also has a liberal MPL license.. doing something commercially-friendly is another goal I didn't write).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with OpenGL - try to look at [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui).

For simplified Qt you may look at [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/).

I think, firstly, you should show us the list of features you want to implement. Than you can get some advices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Windows but simple X11/Xlib calls should do it for Linux (I've written something similar). Anything above it is already a platform on its own. However, X11 only has a few drawing primitives for lines, filling rectangles & polygons. For text use Xft (FreeType), the fonts look much better. The event structure for X11 is fairly simple but elegant; for documention I recommend https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/

I would avoid Xt since it tries to create an 'object oriented' layer over X11 in C which is IMO quite complicated.

Comment: I'd recommend XCB over Xlib, it's much more modern.